# Get custom wp_query search results to appear on search.php

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, search

I have a search.php page in my template which works fine when used with the native search widget, but I am making a search plugin which has a custom wp_query in it and I want those results to appear on search.php INSTEAD of regular search widget results.

My plugin so far works well, I "just" want it outputted in search.php.

I tried adding `pre_get_posts` filter and also `posts_search` action but the filter hook shows "the connection was reset" in the browser and the action hook does the same PLUS it gives a WP Database error on the page where the plugin is loaded.

Relevant part of the function that makes the query:

```
$blog_url = get_bloginfo('url');

    $form = <<<EOH
    <div id="sbc">
    <form method="get" action="{$blog_url}" id="ss-search">
        <input type="text" value="{$search_text}" name="supers" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value = '{$search_text}';}" />
        {$list}
        <input type="submit" id="sbc-submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
    </div>
EOH;


if (isset($_GET['supers'])) {

    global $q;
    // global $q;
    $args = array(
        // 'category__not_in' => 1,
        's' => $_GET['supers'],
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
    );

    $q = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<ul>';
        while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
            $q->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
            echo '</ul>';
            // echo '<br>Posts found :'.$q->found_posts.'<br><br>';
            echo get_pagination_links2();
    } else {
        echo 'no posts found';

    }

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

return $form;

} // end function
```

Comment: It's called via a shortcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixining the form display and the search logic. this is the first bad thing in your code.

Second, the hook you have used are triggered everytime a query run, even the query inside your function, this bring to an infinite loop.

So, first of all separate logic from display:

```
function vkss_super_search_form( $atts = '' ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    // your default params
  ), $atts );
  // some code you have here
  ob_start();
  ?>
  <div id="sbc">
  <form method="get" action="<?php echo $blog_url; ?>" id="ss-search">
  <input type="text" value="<?php $search_text  ?>" name="supers" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value = '<?php echo $search_text; ?>';}" />
  <?php echo $list; ?>
  <input type="submit" id="sbc-submit" value="Search" />
  </form>
  </div>
  <?php
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('vkss_super_search', 'vkss_super_search_form');
```

Previous function print the form via shortcode.

Now you have to run the search when the form is submitted. You want to use the `search.php` but you have to notice that no one force to have that file on a theme, so you have to provide a fallback to `index.php` (just like WordPress does) if that file is not present.

You can use `'pre_get_posts'`, to check if the `'supers'` GET variable is present and if so run change the main query. after that, the `search.php` will be used by WordPress because you are setting a search query.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'vkss_super_search');

function vkss_super_search( $query ) {
  if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_front_page() ) {
    $supers = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'supers', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    if ( empty( $supers ) ) return;
    $query->is_search = true;
    $query->set( 's', $supers );
    // $query->set( 'category__not_in', 1 );
  }
}
```

Note that all this second code block in **unnecessary** if you name your input field `'s'` instead of `'supers'`.

```
<input type="text" value="{$search_text}" name="s" />
```

Comment: But where does my custom wp_query go? The custom query is very important because I'm gonna expand on it to include more things to filter once I get the basics set up. (sorry for the late reply, but this website is not functioning normally, less than 2 hours ago it said there were no replies). Also, it is no problem to use "s" if it will accept my custom filtering, I chose another name because I thought they'd clash.

Comment: I added your last block of code. Now when I click "search" in my plugin, it DOES show the search.php page, but it uses everything from there still. I need it to use data from my custom wp_query. So for example, in my custom query (as you can see above), if there are no results it echoes "no posts found" , but in search.php it says "Your search for $var has returned $var results", and if I search for something that I know doesn't exist, I get the message from search.php and not my custom query.

Comment: @dzimidula you don't need to create a custom `WP_Query`, you have to change the main query to include whatever you want. I've edited the answer adding the commented `'category__not_in'` argument just like you do in question. You have to use that method to run the query that you need. You do not need to pass the `'paged'` method because it is handled by WordPress by default on main query.

Comment: I think it's working. Yes, I have to change the main query. I hardcoded some category ids to exclude now and used my plugin search button and it behaved the way I wanted it to! I could not have come to the solution on my own as I am quite new to WP. Thanks so much for taking the time!